# Return to main window after crash - PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

When I run the following code, it crashes, as expected, because there is no Radio button. As you can see, I have an error output box. **I would like to return to main_window once I click OK in the error popup.** Right now, if I click OK in the error popup, the main_window freezes and the program crashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import traceback
import PySimpleGUI as sg


sg.theme('Material2')   

layout = [  [sg.Text('Test Window', font = 'Comic',text_color='green')],
            [sg.InputText('Use Browse button'), sg.FileBrowse()],
            [sg.Button('Submit'), sg.Button('Cancel')] 
         ]

main_window = sg.Window('OS Met Processor', layout)

try:
    
    while True:
        event, values = main_window.read()
        if event in (None, 'Cancel'):
            break
        
        values = {k: v for k, v in values.items() if v} 
    
        if values['RadioYes']:   
            values = {k: v for k, v in values.items() if v} 
            sg.Popup('Done!')
            main_window.close() 

except Exception as e:
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    sg.popup_ok(f'ERROR!', e, tb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `try` and `except` inside the `while` loop.

try this :

```
while True:
    event, values = main_window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Cancel'):
        break
    
    values = {k: v for k, v in values.items() if v} 
    try:    
        if values['RadioYes']:   
            values = {k: v for k, v in values.items() if v} 
            sg.Popup('Done!')
            main_window.close() 

    except Exception as e:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        sg.popup_ok(f'ERROR!', e, tb)
```